# PBS/Torque: very simple pbsdsh script with PBS_VNODENUM

Tags: shell-script, portable-batch-system, torque

I'm trying to submit the following very simple script to my cluster:

```
#!/bin/sh
#PBS -l nodes=3:ppn=8,walltime=00:01:00
#PBS -M eamorr@mydomain.com
#PBS -j oe
#PBS -m bae
#PBS -N geophysics 

pbsdsh date
pbsdsh echo $PBS_VNODENUM
```

And here is the output:

```
Wed Oct 24 12:52:08 IST 2012
Wed Oct 24 12:52:08 IST 2012
Wed Oct 24 12:52:08 IST 2012
Wed Oct 24 12:52:08 IST 2012
Wed Oct 24 12:52:08 IST 2012
Wed Oct 24 12:52:08 IST 2012
Wed Oct 24 12:52:08 IST 2012
Wed Oct 24 12:52:08 IST 2012
Wed Oct 24 12:52:08 IST 2012
Wed Oct 24 12:52:08 IST 2012
Wed Oct 24 12:52:08 IST 2012
Wed Oct 24 12:52:08 IST 2012
Wed Oct 24 12:52:08 IST 2012
Wed Oct 24 12:52:08 IST 2012
Wed Oct 24 12:52:08 IST 2012
Wed Oct 24 12:52:08 IST 2012
Wed Oct 24 12:52:08 IST 2012
Wed Oct 24 12:52:08 IST 2012
Wed Oct 24 12:52:08 IST 2012
Wed Oct 24 12:52:08 IST 2012
Wed Oct 24 12:52:08 IST 2012
Wed Oct 24 12:52:08 IST 2012
Wed Oct 24 12:52:08 IST 2012
Wed Oct 24 12:52:08 IST 2012
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Surely instead of a list of zeros, I should be getting 0-23???

Really stuck on this and thought I'd ask the community...

Comment: Question probably has to do with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TORQUE_Resource_Manager .

Answer (score -1):

I found this [thread](http://www.supercluster.org/pipermail/torqueusers/2006-August/004111.html) that gives an example of something like this (adapted to your special needs):

> pbsdsh -s bash -c 'echo $PBS_VNODENUM'

Comment: Can you put the example in your answer so this is still useful when that link eventually goes dead?